# routes for user messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message

Im trying to build the functionality that gives users the ability to send each other messages. Ideally, a user can visit another user's profile and click on a link the redirects them to a form in which they will enter the message, and then click send and it will be delivered to the second user's inbox.

Separately, users should be able to visit an inbox page that displays all messages that have been sent to them.

I'm working on the first part now, and having trouble with the routes. Specifically, when I click on the send message link in a user's profile I'm redirected to the user's inbox page instead of being redirected to a form in which I can enter the context of my message and send. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone suggest how I can solve this routing issue?

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    get 'login',    to: 'devise/sessions#new',     as: :login
    get 'logout',   to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
  end

  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'edit_profile'
      get 'create_message'
    end
  end

  resources :messages

  root to: "home#index"
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get' 
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/legal',   to: 'static_pages#legal',   via: 'get'

end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update!(user_params)
    redirect_to @user
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def edit_profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create_message
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password,    :password_confirmation, :current_industry, :years_in_current_industry, :hobbies)
  end

  def sender
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def recipient
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :current_industry, :years_in_current_industry, :hobbies

  #validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  #validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

end
```

messages.rb

```
class Messages < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender
  belongs_to :recipient
  default_scope -> [ order('created_at DESC') ]
  validates :sender_id, presence: true
  validates :recipient_id, presence: true
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Inbox</h1>
```

creates_messages.html.erb

```
<h2>Create Message</h2>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :first_name, autofocus: true %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Send" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Several problems: **1)** You don't show the link pointing to `create_message` action. **2)** `create_message` action does not match `create_messages.html.erb`. **3)** `@user` used in the view is undefined. **4)** Messages model and controller are never used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, path: "", :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }, path_names: {sign_up: "register", sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
resources :users do
   resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]
end
resources :messages, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] #domain.com/messages -> inbox

#app/controllers/messages/new.html.erb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_recipient

   def new
      @message = current_user.messages.new recipient_id: params[:user_id]
   end

   def create
      @message = current_user.messages.new message_params
      @message.sender_id = current_user.id
      @message.recipient_id = @recipient.id
      @message.save
   end

   private

   def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:title, :body, :sender_id, :recipient_id)
   end

   def set_recipient
      @recipient = User.find params[:user_id] if params[:user_id].present?
   end
end

#app/views/messages/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@recipient, @message] do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
   <%= f.text_field :body %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Routes**

The above code will give you the ability to use the following link:

```
#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Send Message", user_message_path(@user) %>
```

You must remember that since Rails is [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), everything you do (routes included) should revolve around objects. This is why you see the `resources` directive in your routing patterns -- it gives you the ability to define a series of [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) based routes with various objects at their core.

I believe your problem is that you are not using the object orientated nature of Rails to proper extent. If you apply the routes as my example above, backed up with the relative methods, should give you the ability to create a very compelling flow.

Comment: Rich, thanks for the quick response. When I implement your changes, I get the following error when following link_to "Send Message", new_user_message_path(@user): 

undefined method `message' for #<User:0x007ffe4258ee20>

@message = current_user.message.new recipient_id: params[:user_id]

any idea on this?